# Contact Us form on a Django Website not sending emails

Tags: python, django

I followed the instructions from the official documentation and another Stack Overflow post to get django-contact-form working on my django website. I need it to send an email. I tried setting up a debugging server through:

```
python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:1025
```

I have a HTML form working with Django on the site. When I click submit on the form, it gives me an acknowledgement that my message has been sent. However, I can't see anything on the Terminal output.

In my settings.py, I have the following:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'my email'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.zoho.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 1025
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'my email'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'my password'
ADMINS = [('name','my email')]
MANAGERS = ADMINS
```

I have also tried it with the SMTP settings for Zoho mail, which is the one that I am currently using. I am not getting any emails in my inbox or the others folder either.

Another thing that I have tried is changing the settings so that the emails get stored in a tmp folder. I don't want to deploy the code on the site until I can test that it works properly.

Any help will be appreciated. I'm not really sure what I'm missing. Let me know if any other files are needed from my end?

edit: This is my form

```
<form method="post"> {% csrf_token %}
        <label style="font-size:16px" for="name">Name: </label> <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your name ...">
        <label style="font-size:16px" for="email">Email: </label> <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Your email ...">
        <label style="font-size:16px" for="body">Message: </label> <textarea name="body" placeholder="Write something ..." style="height:175px"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-xl sr-button">
</form>
```

Comment: Please show your view that is supposed to be sending mails.

Comment: I have well documented help for and excellent results using AWS SES and mailgun to send transactional mails.

Comment: I have added the html part of my form above but I don't have a backend for it because I have installed the django-contact-form app and I'm trying to send emails with that

Comment: Have you configured a list of recipients in the MANAGERS setting?

Comment: @solarissmoke Yes I have tried adding that too

Comment: @solarissmoke I have updated the question to include my settings

Answer (score 0):

Apart from your setup you need to do some additional stuffs also. Like

```
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = "something@something.com"
```

with corresponding

```
EMAIL_HOST='smtp.something.com'
```

and if you use zoho.com and your incoming is not working please check your SPF record and update it ( assuming you have already updated your MX Records)

Comment: I have tried those as well. I can't check SPF and MX records because I don't have access to the super admin account of the organisation. My account is just one of the accounts in the organisation

Comment: @Nikita You can't change those without super admin permission. Sorry I think problem is in SPF Record. I had similar problem and It had been fixed by updating SPF Record